# jquery append text to parent/child id

Tags: jquery, append

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="foo"><p><a href="#" id="clickme<?php echo $num;?>">blah</a></p></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
 <div class="text">blah blah blah blah</div>
</div>
 <p class="date">27/12/12</p>
</div>
```

this structure is repeated so each `#clickme` has a different number at the end

ie: `#clickme2`,`#clickme3` etc using `#clickme<?php echo $num;?>`

What I am trying to do is have a message appear in the `.date` associated with the `#clickme` when someone clicks on `#clickme`

I have tried:

```
$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>').parent().find('.date').append('<span id="msg">blah blah blah blah</span>');
```

Not working.

```
$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>').closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="msg">blah blah blah blah</span>');
```

This one seems to work (kind of) but appends to the pages first `.post`'s `.date` not the one that the `#clickme` is associated with.

please note `<?php echo $num;?>` is not the problem, thats working fine, its just the jquery.

**UPDATE:**

I have found that

`$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>').closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="msg">blah blah blah blah</span>');`

does work but say I click on the third post it shows correctly but if then I click on any posts below that one ie 4th, 5th it remains to append to the third post and not the post associated with the click.

I also have this line aswell to fade the message in/out

```
$('#msg').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

I have tried adding `.remove()` to the end after a delay but that stops it from working at all

```
$('#msg').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast').delay(1000).remove();
```

**full code**

`$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>').closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="msg">blah blah blah blah</span>');
$('#msg').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');`

Answer (score 1):

You want to match every element with the id beginning with `clickme`. You can thus use the [***Attribute Starts With Selector (`[name^="value"]`)***](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=clickme]').closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="alreadyvoted">You already voted for this post</span>');
```

[Demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/daJ7C/1)

If you are looking for the `click` event, you can:

```
$('[id^=clickme]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="alreadyvoted"> You already voted for this post</span>');
});
```

[Demo here (click on the links).](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/daJ7C/3/)

### Update:

As seen o the `click` example above, you shouldn't put the `$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>')` **selector inside a `click()` event**. That will re-run the selector (and will return different elements than the clicked). **Inside the `click()`, use `this`, or `$(this)`.**

To remove after the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`, use a callback function. If you call `remove()`, it will remove right away, as you witnessed. The callback function can be added as below (look at the end):

```
$('#msg').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast').delay(1000, function() { this.remove() });
```

To be more safe, it is better to keep a reference to the added span and call `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` directly to it, instead of reusing a selector (like `$('#msg')`):

```
$('[id^=clickme]').click(function () {
    var alreadyVotedSpan = $('<span id="msg"> You already voted for this post</span>');
    $(this).closest('.post').find('.date').append(alreadyVotedSpan);
    alreadyVotedSpan.fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast').delay(1000, function() { this.remove() });
});
```

[See demo here (notice the use of `$(this)` inside the `click()`).](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/daJ7C/7/)

Comment: `[id^=clickme]` does the same as `$('#clickme<?php echo $num;?>')` going to append OP with further info.

Comment: Did you see the second demo link?

Comment: Yes i did, the code is actually apart of an on click if else (on click if ok do something else show message) so not looking for the click event as its already done.

Comment: I updated the answer. Notice the use of `$(this)`. You are saying that it is a part of a onclick if else. Please add that full onclick/if/else code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So I was resigned to just creating a simple `$('body').append()` "one size fits all" rather then what I wanted but I went away had some food came back later full, calm and rested and then boom lightbulb moment! stick a setTimeout > remove on it:

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=<?php echo $num;?>]').closest('.post').find('.date').append('<span id="msg">blah blah blah blah</span>');
    $('#msg').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#msg').remove();
    }, 3000);
});
```

This removes the original appended message code after fadeOut ready for it to be appended again to the next .post .date associated with the next click.

I had previously tried adding `.delay(2000).remove();` like I said in OP update but that didn't work and infact never does (why do I never remember this lol).

Thank you acdcjunior though for taking the time to help me!